# How to find pixel color in image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, binary-image

I am trying to make the black and white mask. Below image has mask of yellow color of chair. I am making it to white and else everything as black. I have used this color [220, 211, 81] for a mask. If i am finding this pixel color it shows that there is nothing like this. What am i doing wrong ?
**Code:**

```
import cv2

color_to_seek = [220, 211, 81]
original = cv2.imread('image.png')
original = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

amount = 0
for x in range(original.shape[0]):
    for y in range(original.shape[1]):
        r, g, b = original[x, y]
        if (r, g, b) == color_to_seek:
            amount += 1

print(amount)`
```

Image: [image]

I am expecting that yellow mask should replaced by white pixels and everything as black. Is there a difference between mask or pixel color ?. Elaborate little bit ?

Comment: Your color_to_seek needs to be a tuple, but you define it as a list.  You are comparing it to a tuple so it can never be equal.

Comment: @Crapicus. Nothing happened if i changes its type

Comment: It is most definitely a bug though.  There may be more.  FYI (1, 2, 3) is not equal to [1, 2, 3] is my point.  And that's also why I added it as a comment not an answer.  Cheers.

Comment: you are expecting to find __that exact color__ in a _photo_, which always has some noise (and compression artefacts). why? why do you not look for a **range of colors**?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz If there is any answer which you think will be fine kindly share it. I didn't tried this solution.

Comment: use OpenCV's `inRange`, maybe combine with cvtColor to HSV or HSL space

Comment: original = cv2.cvtColor(origina, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) Then do upper and lower for yellow. then do inrange. then so mask for black or white

Comment: original = cv2.imread('image.png')
  
# Convert Image to Image HSV
original = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  
# Defining lower and upper bound HSV  yellow values. ? denote to specified yellow.
lower = np.array([?, ?, ?])
upper = np.array([?, ?, ?])
  
# Defining mask for detecting color
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

Comment: Another thing is... original[x,y]=[220, 211, 81] Or Change to black img[?:?,?:?] = (0,0,0) ? denote specified coordinate of x and y.

Comment: You have a cyan mask, not a yellow one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by [Christoph Rackwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602877/christoph-rackwitz) using the exact color value may be not the best way for the mask extraction.

Using ranges for color comparisons and using color space that has separate luminance and color channels (HSV or LAB for example) could improve results:

[image]

You may need to find thresholds that have an acceptable number of false positives/false negatives for your specific application.

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('room.png')

color_to_seek_rgb = np.array([142, 140, 60])
color_to_seek_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(color_to_seek_rgb.reshape(1, 1, 3).astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV).flatten()

image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# using lower values for H channel as it encodes luminance not a color information
lower_bound = color_to_seek_hsv - [10, 20, 20]
upper_bound = color_to_seek_hsv + [10, 20, 20]
mask = cv2.inRange(image_hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)

cv2.imwrite("mask.jpg", mask)
```